# How can I let a placeholder in a quantity dropdown display something unique?

Tags: php, calculator, dropdown, placeholder, price

In my Joomla shop (J2STORE), under a product, I have a quantity dropdown that let the price be dynamic on the product page. However, I have made the dropdown display a placeholder first, before you select a quantity. The problem is then that the price is still showing - so I need to write some sort of code in the PHP-file, that tells something like "if no quantity is selected, echo this "---" or "if the placeholder is selected, echo this "---"
I still need the quantity dropdown to work afterwards, so I can not just replace the price part.
Can someone help me out, what I can do here?

I have tried talking with the developers, but they do not have time to help me out with this customization.

Comment: Is this a PHP issue to begin with? Does changing the selection actually cause a new HTTP request (either by submitting a form and reloading the page, or via AJAX in the background) - or is this price just calculated and the display updated via JavaScript on the client?

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on Joomla Stack Exchange.  Your question would benefit from some additional context.  Can you include some code and maybe some screenshots of your current output and your desired output.